# Gradle - access other plugin version

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm want to obtain other plugin version from my own plugin. I can't find a way to do that via `PluginContainer` nor `PluginManager`.

For example for `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("some.plugin") version "1.2.3"
    id("my.plugin") version "3.4.5"
}
```

From the code of "my.plugin" I would like to read that "some.plugin" is in version "1.2.3".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access other plugins versions you could do something like:

```
plugins {
    id("base")
    id("org.hidetake.ssh") version "2.10.1"
    id("com.jfrog.artifactory") version "4.29.2"
}

apply plugin: MyPlugin

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project target) {
        // retrieve plugins dependencies from buildscript classpath
        DependencySet pluginDependencies = target.buildscript.configurations.getByName("classpath").allDependencies

        // use the found plugins dependencies
        pluginDependencies.forEach { Dependency classpathDep ->
            println(" Plugin dependency found:  $classpathDep.name, version=$classpathDep.version")
        }
    }
}
```

This will prompt:

```
> Configure project :
 Plugin dependency found:  org.hidetake.ssh.gradle.plugin, version=2.10.1
 Plugin dependency found:  com.jfrog.artifactory.gradle.plugin, version=4.29.2

> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 434ms
```

Comment: you're correct, that's what I wrote in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74153683/529977 and you're correct, this fits the answer. The answer was not "how can I set a validation" (as what I tried to solve) but just "how can I read a version" ..

Answer (score 0):

nop ... still 2022 this is a 
even google [ships tons of lines on it](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:android/src/com/android/tools/idea/gradle/plugin/AndroidPluginInfo.java)

---

even your `api()` declaration ([with version range](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html))

---

nor can I see that [dependency constraints will help us](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html#sec:adding-constraints-transitive-deps)

[in combination](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html#rich-version-constraints)

like

```
class YourPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
  override fun apply(project: Project) {
    project
      .buildscript.dependencies.constraints
      .add("classpath", "com.example:other-plugin") { 
        it.version {
          it.require("[1.0, 2.0)")
        } 
      }
  }
}
```

because you can't add constraints in this gradle phase
ending with

```
   > Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':app:classpath' after it has been resolved.
```

---

**tldr;**
so I don't see anything else than

1. iterate all project build dependencies checking for version
2. await depending plugin [provides a version](https://github.com/ajoberstar/reckon/blob/08be355041276826cef86df308040ddbbec4b45f/reckon-gradle/src/main/java/org/ajoberstar/reckon/gradle/ReckonExtension.java#L142)

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html is JVM specific and even not addresses this aspect

---

btw, I was not successful when trying to use the version constraints for comparison

```
if (project.pluginManager.hasPlugin("com.example.other") == false) {
  throw DependencyVerificationException("This plugin needs com.example.other")
}
project
  .buildscript
  .configurations
  .getByName("classpath")
  .withDependencies {
    it.find {
      it.group == "com.example" &&
      it.name == "other-plugin"
    }
    ?.version
    ?.let { 
      if (DefaultImmutableVersionConstraint.of("1.0") /*no clue how to compare with*/ == it)
       else throw DependencyVerificationException("This plugin needs com.example.other at least with version 1.0")
    } ?: throw DependencyVerificationException("This plugin needs com.example.other")
  }
```

---

btw. because it is related: for testing different versions there are indeed some things out there like https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-stutter